# Accordion script: OnLoad How to Collapse all menu items?

Tags: accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I found [this really lightweight accordion](http://sandbox.unwrongest.com/jquery.accordion/) script.  [This](http://sandbox.unwrongest.com/jquery.accordion/jquery.accordion-1.2.2.source.js) is the function that makes it work .  On page load it automatically shows one of the menu items.  I want it on page load to not show any ... the accordion to be in a collapsed state.

Any ideas or suggestions on what to modify in the script on page load to have the accordion in a collapsed state?

Answer (score 3):

Try setting  {active:false, collapsible:true} in the options